# Casting in trailing return type causes SFINAE to fail

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, c++14

I have re-implemented `boost::hana::is_valid` for study purpose. The use case is:

```
struct Person {
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    auto has_name = is_valid([](auto&& t) -> decltype((void) t.name) {});

    Person jon{"snow"};
    static_assert(has_name(jon), "");
    static_assert(!has_name(1), "");
}
```

Implementation:

```
namespace detail {

template<typename F>
struct is_valid_impl {
    template<typename T, typename = std::result_of_t<F&&(T&&)>>
    constexpr bool operator()(T&&) const noexcept { return true; }

    constexpr bool operator()(...) const noexcept { return false; }
};

}  // namespace detail

template<typename F>
constexpr auto is_valid(F&&)
{
    return detail::is_valid_impl<F>{};
}
```

However, I don't know why Hana's user guide recommends casting the type of the wanted member to `void` (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html)); can't we just use `decltype(t.name)` instead of `decltype((void) t.name)`?

Moreover, the cast to `void` causes the tests to [fail](https://godbolt.org/g/hPf30c) in GCC < 5.3, while without the cast the code [works](https://godbolt.org/g/MAUdb9) for GCC 5.1+. What could be the reason?

Comment: Using `static_cast` instead of C-cast seems to resolve the problem: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/GAMafu).

Comment: If your read the manual it says: *Notice how we cast the result of `x.member` to `void`? **This is to make sure that our detection also works for types that can't be returned from functions, like array types**.*

Comment: I'm inclined to say compiler bug, because if I use a `static_cast` instead of a C-style cast, it's all good: `auto has_name = is_valid([](auto&& t) -> decltype(static_cast<void>(t.name)) {});`

Comment: GCC 7 works no problem

Comment: @101010 Wonder how I could've missed that :)

Answer (score 2):

Can't be more explicit than the documentation:

> @snippet example/tutorial/introspection.cpp non_static_member_from_object
>
> Notice how we cast the result of `x.member` to `void`? **This is to make sure
>   that our detection also works for types that can't be returned from functions,
>   like array types.**

[Link to the docs line](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/doc/tutorial.hpp#L1641)